# React functional component - how do I pass refs back to parent when component returns an array of elements?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, reference

I have a React component that includes a stateless functional component. The inner component runs Lodash `map` on an array of values to return an array of `p` tags.

```js
class Application extends React.Component {

  items = [
    'first',
    'second',
    'third',
  ];

  render() {
    return <div>
            <Paragraphs items={ this.items } />
        </div>;
  }

}

const renderItem = ( item, index ) => {
  return (
    <p key={ index }>{ item }</p>
  );
};

const Paragraphs = ( { items } ) => _.map( items, renderItem );

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

My `Application` component needs references to these DOM elements, so I'd like to pass back a ref for each of the `p` tags back to the parent component. Can anyone suggest the best way to do this? All the examples I've found assume the child component is a single element.

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/andfinally/pen/PeqMQK)

Comment: Did you read docs? https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#exposing-dom-refs-to-parent-components

Comment: I did, thanks. My problem was more related to dealing with an array of elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now in React 16.3 you can create refs with React.createRef() and pass them from parent component to child. [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) is the docs. 
So you can map items in the parent component and extend them with ref property.

I hope this will work for you.

```
class Application extends React.Component {

    items = [
        'first',
        'second',
        'third',
    ].map(item => ({ item, ref: React.createRef() }))

    // you can access refs here: this.items[0].ref
    render() {
        return <div>
            <Paragraphs items={this.items} />
        </div>;
    }
}
const renderItem = (item, index) => {
    return (
        <p key={index} ref={item.ref} > {item.item} </p>
    );
};
const Paragraphs = ({ items }) => _.map(items, renderItem);
ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: O wow, beautiful solution Vitaliy, thanks! In case useful for other people, `React.createRef` requires React 16.3. Some stray spaces have also crept into your tags, like in `< /p>`, which I deleted when I tried this out. Does the trick for me!

Comment: Thx. Didn't notice that. Code was broken during auto formatting.

Answer (score 0):

for starters, you may want to read in here -

- https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html
- https://gist.github.com/gaearon/1a018a023347fe1c2476073330cc5509

And then, if you have grasped the concept of references in react, I have done, some very simple changes( see below ) to the JS file from your codepen's pen.

I am pasting the new pen, with needed specs here - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wjKvvw

```
class Application extends React.Component {

  items = [
    'first',
    'second',
    'third',
  ];
    item_refs = this.items.map(a=>{}) // making an empty list for references
    item_referer = (ele, ind) => { // a callback function to be called in the children where references are to be made
        this.item_refs[ind] = ele;
        console.log("Referring to", this.items[ind], ele) // a simple logging to show the referencing is done. To see open the console.
    }
    // passing the item_referer function as the prop (itemReferer) to children
  render() {
    return <div>
            <Paragraphs items={ this.items } itemReferer={ this.item_referer }/>
        </div>;
  }

}

const renderItem = ( item, index, referToMe ) => {
    // referToMe is the callback function to be called while referencing
  return (
    <p key={ index } ref={(el)=>referToMe(el, index)} >{ item }</p>
  );
};
// get the itemReferer prop passed to Paragraphs component and use it
// render the children.
const Paragraphs = ( { items, itemReferer } ) => items.map((item, index )=>{
    return renderItem(item, index, itemReferer) // passing to refer to the individual item
})

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Go through the code, if you have any questions, let me know :)

Comment: Thank you H S, I went for Vitaliy's approach because it's so concise.

Comment: Hi. Your chosen approach is modern ( in the context of react versions ) one and I gave solution according to the pen you had created earlier. In that pen, the react's version didn't have createRef api, so I created this version. And for sure, both are right solutions. :)

Comment: I see! Thanks for the info.